# soundItem.exportToFile() function doesn't exist in jsfl for Flash Pro CS5

Tags: flash, jsfl, .mov

I'm trying to write a script to export a Flash file in a .mov file as the sound only and the video into a .swf file.  Publishing the .swf is going well, but I'm having trouble with the audio portion.  While trying to follow the example from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WSDB63C432-5816-4c62-94B9-5B3DE6DF137ACS5.html I got the error: TypeError:soundItem.exportToFile is not a function.  Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?